# How to defer long-time simple function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create microservice and in one function I have three other functions, for example:

```
functionA();
functionB();
functionC();

return json({status: processed});
```

All functions are synchronous, but they execute Math operations. functionB is the longest performed, so I would like to use it as for example HTTP request, which is asynchronous.

I tried:

```
functionB() {
    return new Promise(//etc...);
}
```

and

```
async functionB() {
    return 1;
}
```

but my function still is synchronous.

How does Node recognize which function can be run immediately or should go to event loop? Why Promise and async not working in this case?

Comment: I don't know about node.js but in regular js `async` functions are executed asynchronously but not in a seperate threads. So if you do some heavy math it can still impact the performance a lot.

Comment: You might want to look at https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/, but this is probably too broad for SO

Comment: my 2 cents. event loop does not simply defer a task because it's marked as `async`. I can explain a bit deeper, but first what are you trying to do by `async` that func? I feel it's not worth it

Comment: Just deferring the function execution to the future doesn't solve the problem that the function will be blocking the main thread. Maybe what you actually want is to start a new child process.

Comment: So i explain the async part. But like others, I doubt you don't fully understand how that would help you. For you case, this will just influence the exec order of the tasks, it won't help you "unblock" the main thread because your task in indeed computational intense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logs 'foo' then 'bar'

```
function foobar() {
  var p = Promise.resolve();
  p.then(() => console.log('bar'));
  console.log('foo');
  return p;
}
```

While this logs 'bar' then 'foo'.

```
function foobar() {
  var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('bar');
    resolve();
  })
  console.log('foo');
  return p;
}
```

This is because the callback `(resolve, reject) => ...` passed to `new Promise` is called immediately as part of the promise creation process, thus the callback is actually a sync function.

Similarly with async function.

```
async function B() {
  return 1;
}
```

Marking a sync function `async` doesn't magically make it "async". If the function body (`return 1` in this example) consists of all synch operations, then it is the same as the callback passed to `new Promise`, it's still executed synchronously when called.

If you really need to defer the task to next loop iteration, use `setTimeout(cb)` or `setImmediate(cb)` is more promising. That `cb` is async for sure.